# Function to Get Params Cuts Off Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this function to get my params in Javscript, but on occassion, it cuts off my `charge_id` param.

```
 $.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results) {  return results[1] || 0;  }
 };  

 if ($.urlParam('success')) {
    // Get Charge ID from param
    var chargeId = $.urlParam('charge_id') 
 };
```

In this case, the `charge_id` parameter was shortened by the above expression:

```
lvh.me:3001/?charge_id=ch_1hK2X4XiaCv3r8&success=true
```

This is what is returned:

```
ch_1hK2X4Xi
```

Comment: `[\\?&amp;]` is a character set, so it has no order. It's equivalent to `[p&\\;m?a]`.

Comment: Entities aren't replaced in Javascript strings, so just use `&`, not `&amp;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp(name + '=([^&#]+)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results) {
        return results[1] || 0;
    }
};
```

should do the trick. As Barmar points out in the comments, don't use HTML character references in regex.